# Freeing intermediate variable

Tags: c++, memory, free

I was checking a source code and saw that this `for` loop :

```
for (int i=0; i < result1.length(); i++) {
    unsigned char *buff = ascii_to_utf8((unsigned char)result1.at(i));
    result.append((char*)buff);
    free (buff);
}
```

Has been changed to this:

```
for (int i=0; i < result1.length(); i++)
    result.append((char*)ascii_to_utf8((unsigned char)result1.at(i)));
```

The only difference I can see is that in the second code there's no intermediate variable.

My question is, is there a difference between the two code snippets I couldn't see ? is there nothing to `free` in the seconde code ?

------------ EDIT -----------
Here's the source code of ascii_to_utf8:

```
unsigned char* InvoiceXML::ascii_to_utf8(unsigned char c)
{
    unsigned char *out;

    if(c < 128)
    {
        out = (unsigned char *)calloc(2, sizeof(char));
        out[0] = c;
        out[1] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        out = (unsigned char *)calloc(3, sizeof(char));
        out[0] = (c >> 6) | 0xC0;
        out[1] = (c & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        out[2] = '\0';
    }

    return out; 
}
```

Comment: Unless the implementation of `ascii_to_utf8` changed, this code is now leaking with the change.

Comment: The code needs refactoring anyway as it is not RAII enabled.

Comment: I wonder what this function even does, considering that ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 so no conversion would be necessary.

Comment: @interjay I'll check what it does and update my question..

Comment: @interjay updated my OP with the current version of the function

Comment: Is this really compiled in a C++ compiler?  That is, it it compiled as C++ code, or it it compiled as C code?

Comment: What does `result` store? What does it do with its stored values when it gets destroyed?

Comment: @JohnDibling c++ i guess, why ?

Comment: @PeteBecker `result` adds the value of `result1`.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure the question was tagged correctly.  This code uses absolutely nothing that is exclusive to C++, and looks very much like it is C code both in terms of syntax and coding style.

Comment: how about `InvoiceXML::ascii_to_utf8` ? Could it be `C` syntax ?

Comment: What type is result? Is it std::string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what ascii_to_utf8 does; it almost certainly allocates memory, in which case you do need the "free" in there. So the 2nd snippet will leak memory.

Comment: so if the free is inside the ascii_to_utf8, would the second code still leak?

Comment: @jidma: The free can't be inside ascii_to_utf8 because then the return value couldn't be used. But it's possible that it has been modified not to allocate memory at all.

Comment: it can't be, since the function is returning a pointer. If it had already freed that pointer, you'd be using a freed block of memory, which could contain any old crap...

Comment: If `ascii_to_utf8` uses a static char array to hold its result it can return a pointer to that array and then the caller should **not** call free on the pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker so may be the fix was legit ?

Comment: ... which shows the calloc - so, Liam is right with the assumption of a memory leak

Comment: @Andreas - not necessarily. What does `result` store, and what does it do with it when `result` is destroyed? If it's a vector of smart pointers, then, again, deleting the returned pointer is wrong.

Comment: That's true, you need to look at the code for `result.append` as well to properly answer the question... and also the destructor for `result`.

Answer (score 1):

If `ascii_to_utf8` was changed to not allocate memory (for example, by using a static char array for the result), then the caller should not delete the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

If `ascii_to_utf8` does allocate memory, then:

First snippet: if your `result` object **doesn't copy** in `append` function, it's plainly wrong - you are going to store pointers to freed values.

Second snippet: if you `result` object **does copy** in `append` function, it's wrong; if it **does not**, then you need to `free()` that data somewhere, but this snippet is correct.

Also, if `` `ascii_to_utf8 `` does allocate memory via `new`, you should use `delete` instead.

Otherwise (`ascii_to_utf8` doesn't allocate memory):

First snippet is wrong - you shall not `free` statically allocated memory.

Second snippet is correct.

Comment: i updated my question with the current version of the function